# Ember.js - Getting routes and models working together

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i'm learning Ember.js but i'm struggling to figure out why my routes aren't working properly.

Here are the relevant parts of my app.js:

```
// Routes
App.Router.map(function() {

   this.resource('posts', { path: '/posts' });
   this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:id' });

});

// Handle route for posts list
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
        return App.Post.findAll();
    }

});

// Handle route for single post
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(params){

        return App.Post.findById(params.id);
    }

});

// Post model
App.Post = Ember.Object.extend();

App.Post.reopenClass({
    findAll: function(){

        var posts = [];

        $.getJSON("/api/posts").then(function(response){

            response.posts.forEach(function(post){

                posts.pushObject(App.Post.create(post));

            });

        });

        return posts;
    },
    findById: function(id){

        $.getJSON("/api/post/" + id).then(function(response){

            return App.Post.create(response.post);

        });

    }
});
```

Then in my template I have this:

```
<!-- Post list -->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h1>Posts</h1>
        <hr>
        <ul>
            {{#each post in model}}
                <li>{{#linkTo 'post' post}}{{post.title}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>

<!-- Single post -->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <div class="content">
            {{post_content}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I'm having a few issues here. Firstly, the href attribute on the links in the post list are coming out like this:

`#/post/<App.Post:ember217>`

I can fix this by changing my post route to:

```
this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' });
```

But then when I try to navigate directly to a post by using a URL like `/#/post/1` I get an error:
`Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.`

Finally, if I leave my post route how it is (`/post/:id`) then visit the URL `/#/post/1` none of the post data is displayed. I can see the correct API endpoint is called and no errors are shown in the console.

However, if i click through to the single post from the posts list the post is displayed properly but it uses the weird URL that I mentioned earlier - `#/post/<App.Post:ember217>`.

If this helps, this is the JSON the post models are created from:

```
{"post":
   {
      "id":2,
      "title":"Second post",
      "alias":"second-post",
      "postedOn":"2013-08-12 09:11:37",
      "authorId":1,
      "post_content":"Post content"
   }
 }
```

Sorry i know there's quite a bit there - I hope it's enough to give a clear picture of what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: In your `findById`, is missing the `return` in `$.getJSON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving this url `#/post/<App.Post:ember217>` because your dynamic segment is `/post/:id`, you have to change to `yourmodel_id`, in your case is `/post/:post_id`. Using this, by default the route `serialize` method will know that you want the `id` atribute of the `post`, in the url: /post/1, /post/2 etc. And no override will be needed in that case.

You have said that changing to post_id make the url generation works, but the navigation no, when navigate to url directly, but the problem isn't the routing, I think that is because you are using:

```
App.Post.findById(params.id);
```

You have to update to:

```
App.Post.findById(params.post_id);
```

Other problem that I see (don't know if is a typo mistake), you forget the `return` in ajax call:

```
findById: function(id){
  // you must return the ajax  
  return $.getJSON("/api/post/" + id).then(function(response){

    return App.Post.create(response.post);

  });

}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! - I didn't know that you had to return the AJAX call. Using :post_id and returning the AJAX call has sorted this out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ember likes your objects to have an id property for generating the url.  If you are going to use something other than id in the route (such as :post_id) you'll need tell Ember how to deserialize your model for generating the url.

```
 App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

   model: function(params){

      return App.Post.findById(params.id);
   },
   serialize: function(model) {
      return { id: model.get('id') };
   }

 });



 App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

   model: function(params){

      return App.Post.findById(params.id);
   },
   serialize: function(model) {
      return { post_id: model.get('post_id') };
   }

 });
```